# How can I grab a parent node based on multiple child node values?

Tags: xml, xpath

```
<parents>
 <parent>
    <item>
        <name>200</name>
    </item>
    <item>
        <name>201</name>
    </item>
    <item>
        <name>204</name>
    </item>
 </parent>
 <parent>
     <item>
        <name>203</name>
     </item>
 </parent>
</parents>
```

I need the first `parent` node because I have a list of IDs that correspond to items. Consider this:

```
list = ['200', '201'];
```

Because `200` is found in the first `parent` node, I want that `parent` node. If `200` didn't exist, I would still get the parent node because `201` is a value of the `/name/text()` residing in the first `parent`.

My only requirement is that I need to grab the `parent` node if even `one` of the IDs in my `list` is found.

Currently I'm only testing for the first, like so:

`//name/child::text()[.="' . $firstKey . '"]/../../../../`

Where `$firstKey` is a reference to the first element in the list, `200`. This isn't ideal because it doesn't check for all values, but only the first one.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for two solutions -- an XPath 1.0 + XSLT solution and an XPath 2.0 solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I. XPath 1.0 solution using XSLT 1.0 as host**:

Use:

```
/*/parent[item/name = $vList]
```

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:my="my:my">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <my:list>
  <val>200</val>
  <val>201</val>
 </my:list>

 <xsl:variable name="vList" select=
     "document('')/*/my:list/*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:copy-of select="*/parent[item/name = $vList]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<parents>
    <parent>
        <item>
            <name>200</name>
        </item>
        <item>
            <name>201</name>
        </item>
        <item>
            <name>204</name>
        </item>
    </parent>
    <parent>
        <item>
            <name>203</name>
        </item>
    </parent>
</parents>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<parent>
   <item>
      <name>200</name>
   </item>
   <item>
      <name>201</name>
   </item>
   <item>
      <name>204</name>
   </item>
</parent>
```

**Note**: You can pass what is now `<my:list>` as a parameter to the transformation.

**II. Using XPath 2.0**:

```
/*/parent[item/name = ('200', '201')]
```

The XSLT 2.0 - based verification is below"

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:my="my:my">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:copy-of select="*/parent[item/name = ('200', '201')]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document (above), the same correct result is produced.**

Comment: It seems like the `('200', '201')` breaks at the comma when using this not in the context of XSLT but an XPATH interface in various languages? Does that mean they aren't using xpath 2.0 or is it only valid in the context of XSLT?

Comment: @meder: This is standard XPath 2.0 -- any XPath 2.0 engine supports this. For example this is valid in XQuery, as XQuery is a superset of XPath 2.0. So, to answer the question, if a given XPath engine can't evaluate this expression (and most probably throws a syntax error), this means that it doesn't support XPath 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could be of help:

```
//parent[.//item[name[text()='200' or text()='201']]]
```

You'll have to construct the innermost predicate (with the `text()='200' or ...`) programmatically, though. I'm not certain within which context you are using this, but since you're using a variable reference I'm assuming XSLT. I'll see if there's something more suitable...

**EDIT**: The only thing I can think of is concatenating all your keys with some symbol that you're sure they'll never contain as separator. For example:

```
200#201#...
```

Then use the XPath `contains` function:

```
//parent[.//item[name[contains('200#201#...', normalize-space(text()))]]]
```

The first argument of contains would then have to be your concatenated keys, perhaps passed in as a variable. Function `string-join` would be good for this, but I believe it's only available in XPath 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

If you have XSLT 2.0, you can say

```
<xsl:variable name="list" select="(200, 201)" />
<xsl:variable name="theParent" select="(//parent[item/name = $list])[1]" />
```

The `=` works as an existential comparison, returning true if any item in the nodeset on the left side is equal to any item in the sequence on the right side of the `=`.

(Untested.)